# Using Curl in Bash to output multiple IP address locations as a json file

Tags: json, bash, curl

What I'm attempting to accomplish is to combine all the below steps and Bash commands into a script that will result in a .json file that holds all the json formatted locations of each IP address.

STEP 1 - The 5 variables below define each command to read each access log file and output just the IP addresses.

```
a=(cat /media/sf_sandbox/logs/access_log.log |awk '{print $1}' |sort)
b=(cat /media/sf_sandbox/logs/access_log_01.log |awk '{print $1}' |sort)
c=(cat /media/sf_sandbox/logs/access_log_02.log |awk '{print $1}' |sort)
d=(cat /media/sf_sandbox/logs/access_log_03.log |awk '{print $1}' |sort)
e=(cat /media/sf_sandbox/logs/access_log_04.log |awk '{print $1}' |sort)
```

STEP 2 - Below "variable f" adds together the output result of each command of the STEP 1 variables.

```
f=($a + $b + $c + $d + $e)
```

STEP 3 - Below "variable g" sorts through the output list of IP addresses and eliminates the duplicates.

```
g=(cat /media/sf_sandbox/logs/ip_sorted.txt |awk '!x[$0]++' ip_sorted.txt)
```

STEP 4 - Below "variable g" outputs the final result list of unique IP addresses.

```
echo '$g' ip_sorted.txt
```

STEP 5 - The below curl command reads the IP address and outputs the final result information in json format.

```
curl ipinfo.io/5.254.144.88

{
 "ip": "5.254.144.88",
 "hostname": "No Hostname",
 "city": "",
 "region": "",
 "country": "SE",
 "loc": "59.3294,18.0686",
 "org": "AS42708 Portlane AB"
```

}

My Question is, is there a way I can create a string and concatenate it to loop through each IP address in the ip_sorted.txt to output the results of all the IP addresses
using the curl command? Finally, place the results in a .json file.

Comment: very good for a first Q, but you'll get much faster/better responses by include sample output from each of your steps. I don't see how you expect to use `+` to "add" ip.addr values. Wouldn't a sample of step 2 be `f=(8.8.8.8 + 127.0.0.1 + 192.168.1.1 + 2607:f8b0:4009:808::200e)`. You can't add those!  And you have other unknowables that would be simplified by including sample data and output. Also read about `sort -u`, AND there are a bunch of syntax errors, did you run your script thru `http://shellcheck.net`. Good luck.

Comment: You can probably do `awk '{print $1}' /p/2/l/f1 /p/to/l/f2 /p/to/l/f3  ... | sort -u` and be 1/2 way there.

Comment: I tried working it out step by step and got to the point where it'll sort the IP addresses and get rid of the duplicates. I can't figure out how to extract all the log pages IP addresses into one .txt file. Then use that file to take out the duplicates. then curl all the IPs to a json format.

Comment: `awk '{print $1}' /p/2/l/f1 /p/to/l/f2 /p/to/l/f3 ... | sort -u  | while read ip ; do curl ipinfo.io/"${ip}"; done` ?  Good luck.